# Widget Area not showing in Wordpress Staging Site

Tags: wordpress

I am having a weird issue with my footer widgets on a site I am working on. In my local environment the widgets appeared just fine, but on the staging site, the widgets do not appear. When I look at the live preview, it says I have 3 widget areas but they don't appear on this page. They are in the footer.php file (displays on every page), which is running and displaying the non-widget related parts on the screen. Like I said, it was working fine in my local environment. Any ideas?

Edit: I forgot to mention that when I view it under Appearance>Widgets, it says my site has no widget areas.

Another Edit: I found these errors in the error log. In the first one, I noticed the 7.4. Does that mean it is loading php 7.4? I built this theme in local using php 8. Could that be the issue?

```
[06-Aug-2021 13:13:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.7.4.lin' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.7.4.lin: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[06-Aug-2021 13:14:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home3/growinj1/public_html/staging/8458/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-sidebars-controller.php on line 104
[06-Aug-2021 13:15:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_merge(): Expected parameter 3 to be an array, bool given in /home3/growinj1/public_html/staging/8458/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-widgets.php on line 379
[06-Aug-2021 13:15:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home3/growinj1/public_html/staging/8458/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-widgets.php on line 426
```

Here is my functions.php:

```
    <?php 
        function smm_files() {
            wp_enqueue_script('header-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/header.js'), NULL, '1.0.0', true);
            wp_enqueue_style('main-styles', get_stylesheet_uri());
            wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arsenal:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap');
        }
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'smm_files');
    
        function smm_features() {
            add_theme_support('title-tag');
            register_nav_menu('headerMenuLocation', 'Header Menu Location');
        }
        add_action('after_setup_theme', 'smm_features');
    
        function smm_widgets_init() {
    
            register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => 'Footer Sidebar 1',
                'id' => 'footer-sidebar-1',
                'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
                'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
                'after_title' => '</h3>',
                ) );
                register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => 'Footer Sidebar 2',
                'id' => 'footer-sidebar-2',
                'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
                'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
                'after_title' => '</h3>',
                ) );
                register_sidebar( array(
                'name' => 'Footer Sidebar 3',
                'id' => 'footer-sidebar-3',
                'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
                'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => '</aside>',
                'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
                'after_title' => '</h3>',
                ) );
        }
        add_action( 'widgets_init', 'smm_widgets_init' );
    
        function smm_post_thumbnails() {
            add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        }
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'smm_post_thumbnails' );
    
    //Page Slug Body Class
    function add_slug_body_class( $classes ) {
        global $post;
        if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
        }
        return $classes;
        }
        add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_slug_body_class' );
```

And here is the footer.php:

```
        <footer>
            <div id="footer-sidebar" class="secondary">
                <div id="footer-sidebar1">
        <?php
            if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1')){
                dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1');
            } endif;
        ?>
                </div>
                <div id="footer-sidebar2">
        <?php
            if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-2')){
                dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-2');
            } endif;
        ?>
                </div>
                <div id="footer-sidebar3">
        <?php
            if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-3')){
                dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-3');
            } endif;
        ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-el">
                <span>&copy 2021 SiteName</span><span><a href="<?php echo site_url('/privacy-policy') 
                            ?>">Privacy Policy</a></span>
            </div>
        </footer>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to
check the widgets inside Appearance>>Widgets if they are properly placed?
Is the visibility set correctly?
Also be sure you don’t have issues regarding your site hosting.
Also try to deactivate plugin one by one and check

Comment: Tried all that. I just tried applying the theme in the live environment. It works fine there. So I am thinking it must be something related to the staging environment set up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the staging site is set up as "site-domain.com/staging/8458".

It works fine on the live site, so it must be the way that Wordpress sees the location of the staging site.